# GSON sorting keys automatically in toJson()

Tags: android, gson

I have the below code which I want to serialize.

```
class .. {
  public transient long id;
  public Date steps;
  public int days;
  public List<Integer> next;
}
```

I output this to JSON string using the below code.

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(obj)
```

The output which I get is as under

```
{"days":2, "next": [3,5,8], "steps": "Nov 24, 2020 9:50:09 PM"}
```

As you can see, it is sorting output in alphabetic order. I do no want this. I want it to be in order I defined in the class i.e.

```
{"steps": "Nov 24, 2020 9:50:09 PM", "days":2, "next": [3,5,8]}
```

**How can this be achieved ?**

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6365851/8298909. It looks like the answer is "it's not possible unless you write your own serializer or use a different library". (Edit: oh, hm, I didn't see the android tag and so I didn't expect to be able to one-vote close this question.)